# Styles will only apply if the selected element is the first child of a specific parent in CSS

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I want to find how to select the `.if-first-child` element that's the first element of a specific parent, which in this case is `<div>`.

```
<div class="no-css">
    <p class="if-first-child">The style will only take effect here!</p>
    <p>No style here..</p>
    <p class="if-first-child">No style here..</p>
</div>
<div class="no-css">
    <nav>
        <p class="if-first-child">No style here..</p>
    </nav>
</div>
```

In other words, e.g. I want to apply `background-color: black;` in the `.if-first-child` only if it's the first child of `<div>`.

Keep note that the `div p:first-child` selector will still select the `.if-first-child` element even though it have a `<nav>` parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unintended, I found how to select the target when I'm exposing in the question that the `div p:first-child` selector will still select the `p:first-child` element if it have a `<div>` grandparent.

```
div > .if-first-child:first-child { 
    background-color: black;
}
```

That will only target the first-child `.if-first-child` which is a direct child of `<div>`. It will not target a grandchild `.if-first-child:first-child`.

Answer (score 0):

In simple, you can try this as well...

```
.if-first-child{color:red}
div .if-first-child{color:green}
```

It will target only first child to change the color of the text and rest will apply default text color.